AssertDataFrameEqual doesn't throw error with None dataframe in Pyspark
When I try to assert a dataframe using the PySpark API, if a dataframe is none, I do not get the assertion error, but instead, the method returns false. Is it a bug, or should  I handle my test verification differently?
from pyspark.testing.utils import assertDataFrameEqual
assertDataFrameEqual(spark.createDataFrame([("v1", "v3")]), None) 
# False

from pyspark.testing.utils import assertDataFrameEqual
assertDataFrameEqual(spark.createDataFrame([("v1", "v3")]), spark.createDataFrame([("v1", "v2")]))
# PySparkAssertionError


When running the code you run, I do get an error for your code:
[INVALID_TYPE_DF_EQUALITY_ARG] Expected type Union[DataFrame, ps.DataFrame, List[Row]] for `expected` but got type None.

I do not see why this could be different for you: all versions containing this function start with the same check for None values, as found in the code:
    if actual is None and expected is None:
        return True
    elif actual is None:
        raise PySparkAssertionError(
            error_class="INVALID_TYPE_DF_EQUALITY_ARG",
            message_parameters={
                "expected_type": "Union[DataFrame, ps.DataFrame, List[Row]]",
                "arg_name": "actual",
                "actual_type": None,
            },
        )
    elif expected is None:
        raise PySparkAssertionError(
            error_class="INVALID_TYPE_DF_EQUALITY_ARG",
            message_parameters={
                "expected_type": "Union[DataFrame, ps.DataFrame, List[Row]]",
                "arg_name": "expected",
                "actual_type": None,
            },
        )

This means that in your case it should return the error I got, getting raised by the last elif.
Despite it being unclear what the reason is for your different behaviour, a valid comparison based on the types would be wrapping the None in a list.
Edit: Note that the code was run on Azure Databricks DBR 14.3LTS, pyspark 3.5.0.

It seems to be a databricks behaviour (bug). I just tested in raw spark (3.5.2) and worked as you said, throwing the exception, but in a databricks notebook  (DBR 13.3 Spark 3.4.1) it only returns false

This functionality was added in Spark 3.5.0, but Databricks apparently added this functionality earlier. In the very first version of this function, which was the 3.5.0-rc1 release of pyspark, it still returned False in that case. They apparently exposed that early version of the function in DBR 13.3LTS, as can be seen in the release notes in update SPARK-44397.
